# Define type for filename string with extension in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I want to define the type for a filename field in my object. It'll have a string containing name of the file along with extension, of the file uploaded by user.

For example:

```js
{
    icon: "my_icon.svg"`
}
```

I want to define a type that will enforce that the filenames always end with ".svg". Right now I am doing this (and needless to say, it's not working)

```js
{
    icon: string & ".svg"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [template literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) for that:

```
let x: `${string}.svg`;

x = 'foo';     // Error: Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '`${string}.svg`'.
x = 'bar.svg'; // This is ok
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
export type FileName = `${string}.svg` | `${string}.txt`
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck